# String Matching in Ruby

Tags: ruby, string

I'm building a SaaS app that allows people to send an SMS txt to a number and donate to a non-profit.

One of the issues I'm running into is validating the initial txt string to make sure it's formed properly. When someone sends the initial txt it should either be "{{amount}} {{fund_keyword}}" or "{{amount}}", where `fund_keyword` is something the account holder inputted earlier.

Here's an example of some tests that should pass:

```
str1 = "1"               #should return "Amount must be > $4."
str2 = "7"               #should return "Here's the link to donate." 
str3 = "90 10"           #should return "10 is not a valid fund."   
str4 = "5invalidfund"    #should return "5invalidfund is not a valid fund."
str5 = "90validfund"     #should return "90validfund is not a valid fund."
str6 = "50 invalidfund"  #should return "invalidfund is not a valid fund."
str7 = "50 validfund"    #should return "Here's the link to donate."        
str8 = "2 invalidfund"   #should return "invalidfund is not a valid fund."
str9 = "2 validfund"     #should return "Amount must be > $4."         
str10 = "10000"          #should return "Here's the link to donate."
str11 = "100 validfund blahblah" #should return "Please format correctly."
```

And here's the route I was going down to solve this:

```
def valid_text str, account
  if str.length > 1
    array = str.split(" ")
  else 
    array = str
  end

  if str.length >= 1 && array.length == 1 && array.to_i < 4
    return "Amount must be at least $4."
  elsif str.length >= 1 && array.length == 1 && array.to_i > 4
    return "Here's the link to donate."
  elsif array.length == 2 && account.funds.none? {|f| f == array.last }
    return "#{array.last} is not a valid fund."
  elsif array.length == 2 && array.first.to_i < 4 && account.funds.any? {|f| f == array.last }
    return "Amount must be at least $4."
  elsif array.length == 2 && account.funds.any? {|f| f == array.last }
    return "Here's the link to donate."
  elsif array.length > 2
    return "Please format your txt as 'amount fund'. You don't have to specify a fund."
  end
end
```

My question is: what method can parse incoming txt (str*) and return the proper message?

Comment: avoid spaghetti code, prefer extracting all validation logic into a dedicated class (`MessageValidator`) where you'll put each condition logic into their own method. For example: `def valid_format?`

Comment: What's your question ?

Comment: I have to agree with @Pierre-LouisGottfrois, you should really state your actual question. I will remove my down vote if you do.

Comment: Just updated with the question, hopefully that's clearer. If not, please let me know and I'll try to elaborate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
def donate input_string
  amount, fund_keyword, invalid = input_string.split

  unless invalid.nil? && amount[/^\d+$/]
    return "Please format your txt as 'amount fund'. You don't have to specify a fund."
  end

  if fund_keyword && !account.funds.include?(fund_keyword)
    return "#{fund_keyword} is not a valid fund."
  end

  if amount.to_i < 4
    return "Amount must be at least $4."
  end

  "Here's the link to donate."
end
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use just `Regexp`:

```
def donate input_string
   re = /^(?:(?<sum>\d+)|(?<sum>\d+)(?:\s+(?:validfund(?<err_fmt>.*)|(?<err>.*)))|(?<err>.*)?)$/ 
   m = input_string.strip.match(re)

   return "#{m[:err]} is not a valid fund." if m[:err]

   return "Please format correctly." if !m[:err_fmt].empty?

   return "Amount must be > $4." if m[:sum].to_i <= 4

   "Here's the link to donate."
end
```